# Browser not opening using Selenium and Kora on Google Colab

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory, kora

The browser will not open with the "get" object while using Google Colab with Selenium and Kora.  Here is my code:

```
from kora.selenium import wd
website = "https://www.espn.com"
wd.get(website)
```

It just returns "completed" and nothing happens.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the browser won't open, you mean that you are expecting a window to open?
Because if so, that's just not possible. It runs headless. You can't redirect the server's - that colab is hosted on - monitor image to yours.